# Could a frozen ocean support a nomadic race of people?

Tags: geography, fantasy-races, ocean

This is a another sequel to my Plutonian questions, but I’ve decided to take a break from them and focus on another part of the world.

Basically, my version of Pluto has five continents, each a similar distance to one another

However, said oceans are covered in thick ice sheets, ones strong enough support the weight of anyone walking on them.

I came up with the idea of a Tusken Raider like 
race with technology similar to that of the Inuits inhabiting these frozen oceans, and preying on anyone passing through.

What I’m wondering though...

Is whether or not a nomadic people like them could survive on top of a frozen ocean.

Comment: You already know about Inuit, and that they live above a frozen ocean. What is your problem then?

Comment: BLT Bub there’s liquid water beneath the ice, and fish live in this water.

Comment: Considering the fact I live among people who did just that, I'm sort of confused why you're asking if it's possible.

Comment: I’m sorry about my question.

Comment: Covered in thick ice-sheets? You mean, permanently and ubiquitously covered in ice-sheets?
How the oxygenation of those waters go? Or what else those fishes breath?
If it's not oxygen, what are the chances they are edible by the oxygen-breathing organisms? (I know that many anaerobic bacteria don't spoil the food. However, I wouldn't eat a higher order animal that breaths chlorine, sulfur dioxide or NOx)

Comment: Just to clarify are there rocks on your planet or are all the continents covered with ice aswell?

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica: Inuits don't live above a frozen ocean. They live on land and hunt in open water from kayaks or ice floes. They also sometimes hunt on land: muskoxen, snowhares, etc.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen, the Inuit I live beside, whose ancestors were the Copper Inuit,  used to spend the winters on the ice, living in snowhouses and hunting seal for food.

Comment: Can you clarify the thickness of the ice?  Supporting the weight to walk on is only an 3 inches of ice.  7 for a car.  https://www.almanac.com/content/ice-thickness-safety-chart

Answer (score 3):

Alan Dean Foster makes a good case for the possibility in his 1974 novel **[Icerigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icerigger)**. You might want to read that for inspiration.

A human spaceship crashes on the icy world of Trần-Ky-Ky, where they encounter and befriend a tribe of nomads that skate the ice steppes. They built the titular icerigger from remains of their spaceship and attempt to travel to a human base elsewhere on the plant. There is a barbaric horde threatening the natives, who live by hunting ice whales.

The plot is basically the same as Poul Anderson's earlier *The Man Who Counts* (vt. *War of the Winged Men*), just set on an icy planet instead of a mostly watery planet.

There is a somewhat detailed review of the novel [here](https://yellowedandcreased.wordpress.com/2013/03/27/icerigger-alan-dean-foster/).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**It depends on how thick the ice is.**

If the global ocean is fully frozen over, I suspect the ice is thick. Really, *really* thick.

Consider that Jupiter's moon Europa, a glacier world in our solar system, is considered to have internal tidal heating on the same order of magnitude as Earth's core-convected heating. Despite that heat, its crust is a *minimum* of 3 kilometers thick. Granted, its a smaller world than Earth, and it has a lot more water, but it provides a useful baseline to compare to: worlds that are hot on the inside can still be really cold on the outside - cold enough to make the ice *thick*.

The problem with kilometer-thick ice is that there's no way to get food through it. The Inuit can live on the ice because it's thin enough to fish through. There is no way for a low-tech species to drill through anything several orders of magnitude thicker.

There are a few possible workarounds.

- You could find some mechanism to provide a lot more internal heating, thinning the ice significantly. Try dumping in a ton of radioactive elements or adding some large moons to produce tidal heating.
- Add an insulating atmosphere to warm the surface up. You'll kind of need this anyway if you want it to be habitable - though at temperatures cold enough to freeze over an entire ocean, I'm not sure if an atmosphere is really sustainable in the long term.
- Some oases on the ice may be found around cryovolcanoes and fissures in the crust. Places where the ocean leaks out may have thinner ice - and they may directly bring food to the surface.

Comment: "If the global ocean is fully frozen over" what will those fishes breath? Hydrogen sulfide maybe?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Maybe. Photosynthesis won't be viable so plants definitely won't be providing the oxygen. Alternatively, convection within the ice shell could bring surface oxygen to the ocean over time.

Comment: then those Tusken Raider Inuits better have a metabolism able to handle sulfur compounds in large amounts, the humans won't survive on such diets.

Comment: If the world is totally covered in ice, what materials could one use to make weapons? Or fishing gear?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I think the conclusion we're approaching is that a glacial world is not ideal for life. Clothes, tools, gear and weapons would probably have to be animal-based.

Comment: I'd rather say it's not ideal for life above the ice. And an aquatic life with a thick ice cover is not conducive to a technology sophisticated race (can't use open fire, hard to apply thermal insulation under water - energetic experiments run the risk of boiling the experimenter), not likely a place for a space farer race to evolve. May make a good setup for psionically able races, tho.